# Hide Process Command Line

Tags: java, command-line

In Java, you can execute a process and pass command line arguments to it via Runtime.getRuntime().exec().

The arguments you passed into the program can be seen in the task manager or the process explorer. I want to know if there is a way to hide or clear that command history, so that it can be seen by neither.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the external process? (Is it Java? If not, is it native code that you've written? Or if it's a command from a library, which library is it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide the process or the full command that started it. Whatever you pass as command to `Runtime#exec` will show and there is no way around it.

Your alternatives are:

- Integrate the functionality into your application instead of starting a new process. If it's your own native code, you can use JNI to run it. If not your code, you can look for a Java library that does what it does. This is what I would recommend.
- Pass the arguments via IPC (stdin/out, tcp, etc..).
- Read the arguments from a temporary configuration file that will be deleted once the process starts.